# Can I make Neptune talk to git?

Tags: git, github, machine-learning, neptune

In [Neptune](https://neptune.ml/) (this machine learning experiment tracker) is it possible to make it git-aware? I mean - using `.gitignore` for excluded files and saving commit hashes for each run?

In particular, when I review an already finished job, can I go directly to GitHub commit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting form version 2.0 Neptune provides integration with git, see: https://docs.neptune.ml/advanced-topics/git-integration/.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to implement for sure, but afaik till now it is not done. I think such feature will available when Neptune has support for git. It is on the product roadmap.